# Calculating percentages for single column

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

So the outcome i would like is for '% Of Tracks' to display each genres percentage of the total number of tracks

```
SELECT Genre.Name, Count (Genre.GenreID) as 'No Of Tracks', 
(Genre.GenreID) as '% of Tracks' 
From Genre, Track
Where Genre.GenreID = Track.GenreID
Group by Genre.Name
```

Not sure if i set it up correctly would appreciate some advice

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Genre.Name, COUNT(Genre.GenreID) AS 'No Of Tracks', 
    ROUND(100.0 * COUNT(Genre.GenreID) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Tracks), 2) AS '% of Tracks' 
FROM Genre
LEFT JOIN Track
    ON Track.GenreID = Genre.GenreID
GROUP BY Genre.Name
```

Note that I have replaced your join with an explicit one.  Also, the query `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Genre` is not correlated, so the query optimizer should be able to take advantage of this when executing.

Comment: Should it be explicit instead of implicit. I'm confused.

Comment: Explicit is a dirty word, so I used implicit instead :-)

Comment: Aha! I intentionally removed that word from my answer for the same reason. ;)

Comment: Thanks. I'm still getting a hang of joins, i thought i might need one but wasn't sure how to implement it. Just as a a follow up question how would i get the percent to round down to 2dp

Comment: Use `ROUND(percentage, 2)`

Answer (score 0):

You have to divide the count of `Track`s per `Genre` with the total number of `Tracks`:

```
SELECT
    g.Name,
    COUNT(*) AS 'No of Tracks',
    (COUNT(*) * 100.0) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Tracks) AS '% of Tracks'
FROM Genre g
LEFT JOIN Tracks t
    ON t.GenreID = g.GenreID
GROUP BY g.GenreID, g.Name
```

Notes:

1. Use `JOIN` syntax instead of the old-style (using comma).
2. Use meaning full table aliases to improve readability.

Answer (score 0):

To get the number of tracks per genre you need to group the tracks by `GenreID` and divide that count by the total number of tracks:

```
SELECT Genre.Name AS Genre, 
       CONVERT(nvarchar, CAST(100.00*COUNT(Tracks.TrackId)/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Tracks) AS decimal(8,2))) + '%' AS 'Of Total Tracks'
FROM Genre
INNER JOIN Tracks ON (Genre.GenreId = Tracks.GenreId)
GROUP BY Tracks.GenreId, Genre.Name
```

This gives you (for example) this result:

```
Genre      Of Total Tracks
---------- -------------------------------
Classic    16.67%
Pop        33.33%
Rock       50.00%
```